# tif file has no values

Tags: r, geotiff-tiff

I have a .tif file (about 380 mb) that I am trying to load in R and plot.

```
file<-raster('tiffname.tif')
```

It is a formal class Raster Layer with the following information

```
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 40000, 40000, 1.6e+09  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.00025, 0.00025  (x, y)
extent      : 80, 90, 30, 40  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84+towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : \Data\trial\tiffname.tif 
names       : X40N_080E_mtc02
```

Why are there no values for this tif file? Is that why I am unable to plot it?

Comment: What tells you there are no values for this tif file? Some error message?

Comment: @Spacedman Usually there is a values row after names that gives the min and the max pixel values, which is not here. There is no error message and I do not get a plot for the tif file when I use plot (file)

Comment: @tg110 what does `getValues(file)` produce?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this to see if you get the values row:

```
#load raster
file<-raster('tiffname.tif')
file <- setMinMax(file)
#print raster attributes
file
```

Comment: Shouldn't setMinMax be applied to a RasterLayer class? so first `file<-raster('tiffname.tif')` and then `file <- setMinMax(file)`

Comment: You are totally right. Fixed.